# Angular 4 On select change get attribute data value

Tags: angular, typescript

My code in component.html

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" [(ngModel)]="o.id" formControlName="optionals" (change)="menuChange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let menu_optional of menu_optionals" value="{{ menu_optional.id }}" [attr.data-somedata]="menu_optional.id">{{ menu_optional.name }}</option>
</select>`
```

And thi my component.ts

```
menuChange(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
}
```

And return is `undefined`

I want get value in data-somedata..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As your `attr.data-some-data` value is the same as `value` you can simply write:

```
console.log(event.target.value);
```

But if you really want to get that data-attribute then use the following code:

```
const selectEl = event.target;

const val = selectEl.options[selectEl.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-somedata');
// or
const val = selectEl.options[selectEl.selectedIndex].dataset.somedata;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this :

use (ngModelChange) instead of (change)

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" [(ngModel)]="o.id" formControlName="optionals" (ngModelChange)="menuChange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let menu_optional of menu_optionals" [value]=" menu_optional.id" [attr.data-somedata]="menu_optional.id">{{ menu_optional.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the people, who are using MatSelect (Angular material >1) & Reactive form, below one worked for me

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <mat-select placeholder="Field 1" 
      [formControl]="form.controls['field1']" 
      (change)="dropDownChnge($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let fieldOpt of fieldOpts.options" [attr.data-fieldId]="fieldOpts.fieldId" [value]="fieldOpt.id">{{ fieldOpt.name }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Component.js**

```
dropDownChnge(event) {
    let target = event.source.selected._element.nativeElement;
    let selectedData = {
      fieldId: target.getAttribute('data-fieldId'),
      valueId: event.value,
      value: target.innerText.trim()
    };
    console.log(selectedData);
}
```

If there is best solution or anything wrong in this solution, please let me know, just curious to know :-)

Comment: +1 for your solution. Just to avoid the console `event.source.selected` `undefined` error, I added an `if/else` statement in the `(selectionChange)` event function, by considering a possible empty selected option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60386234/2149425

Answer (score -2):

For Angular material > 7

**Component.ts**

```
menuChange(event) {
// _getHostElement : Gets the current Host DOM element
console.log(event.option._getHostElement().getAttribute('data-somedata'));
}
```