# How to write a custom data attribute for a 'mat-select' element in Angular Material 9

Tags: select, multidimensional-array, angular-material, custom-data-attribute, angular-ngfor

I'm trying to set a custom data attribute (`data-tag`) for a `mat-select` element in Angular Material 9. The following is the `HTML` and `TS` code that I'm using, but nothing happens by inspecting the webpage code into the browser:

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Course</mat-label>
        <mat-select [formControl]="subjectControl" required>
            <mat-option>-- None --</mat-option>
            <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let course of subjects" [label]="course.semester" [disabled]="course.disabled">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let subject of course.courses" [value]="subject.subjectName" [attr.data-tag]="subject.subjectSemester">
                    {{ subject.subjectName }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-optgroup>
        </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS:**

```
export interface SubjectGroup {
    disabled?: boolean;
    semester: string;
    courses: Subject[];
}
export interface Subject {
    subjectName: string;
    subjectSemester: string;
}

export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
    subjectControl = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
    subjects: SubjectGroup[] = [
        {
            semester: "Semester 1",
            courses: [
                {
                    subjectName: "Course 1",
                    subjectSemester: "1° Semester"
                },
                {
                    subjectName: "Course 2",
                    subjectSemester: "1° Semester"
                },
                {
                    subjectName: "Course 3",
                    subjectSemester: "1° Semester"
                },
                {
                    subjectName: "Course 4",
                    subjectSemester: "1° Semester"
                },
                {
                    subjectName: "Course 5",
                    subjectSemester: "1° Semester"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            semester: "Semester 2",
            courses: [
                {
                    subjectName: "Course 1",
                    subjectSemester: "2° Semester"
                },
                {
                    subjectName: "Course 2",
                    subjectSemester: "2° Semester"
                },
                {
                    subjectName: "Course 3",
                    subjectSemester: "2° Semester"
                },
                {
                    subjectName: "Course 4",
                    subjectSemester: "2° Semester"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
}
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860096/angular-4-on-select-change-get-attribute-data-value), but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Thank you

**#Edit 1:**

I tried also:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let subject of course.courses" [value]="subject.subjectName" [attr.data-tag]="subject ? subject.subjectSemester : null">
```

but nothing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally **SOLVED**:

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Course</mat-label>
        <mat-select
            [formControl]="subjectControl"
            [attr.data-tag]="this.subjectControl.value"
            required
        >
            <mat-option>-- None --</mat-option>
            <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let course of subjects" [label]="course.semester" [disabled]="course.disabled">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let subject of course.courses" [value]="subject.subjectName"><!--here I have to set [value] to `.subjectName` or `.subjectSemester` to show it into the `data-tag`-->
                    {{ subject.subjectName }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-optgroup>
        </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

As written in the comments of the code, I have to put the `[attr.data-tag]` into the `mat-select` equal to `this.subjectControl.value`, and set `[value]` of `mat-option` equal to the value to store into `[attr.data-tag]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct to me. I tried adding it to an existing stackblitz example, and it showed up in the HTML. Maybe it will help to figure it out:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-compare-with?embed=1&file=app/app.html

```
<mat-option class="mat-option ng-star-inserted" data-tag="Three" role="option" ng-reflect-value="[object Object]" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-29" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
```

Comment: Hello @MattNienow, thanks a lot for your answer and time to reply. I'm new to Angular. I tried to visit your link running your code but, sorry, maybe I'm doing something wrong, because I don't see the `data-tag` attribute in the webpage's source code... I realized a screencast to show you what I have done: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EQycenZ4Evd-TZ8TJljJn7sMJcw3ZFi9

Comment: @RiccardoVolpe Your screenshot is not public. Are you expecting the `data-tag` to be on the mat-select element. Its on the mat-option element when you open the menu.

Comment: Hello @MattNienow, try this one: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EQycenZ4Evd-TZ8TJljJn7sMJcw3ZFi9/view?usp=sharing ... I would store the selected option into the data-tag. The intent is to generate automatic tags based on input form values, by applying post processing on the content of the data-tag attribute... That is, loop into the form to take all data-tag attributes (based on input values) on which apply the post processing to generate the tags